# is there a way to know my app actions review status in console?

Tags: app-actions

in app actions deployment documentation i can see
"After you upload your app to the Play Console, we'll contact you at the email in Play Console with more information regarding the status of your App Actions review."
but i didn't receive any mail regarding this after uploading my AAB with actions.xml to open testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [support form](https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support) to ask about review status.  There is no way to check for yourself.

Comment: yes i have asked for my review status

but [here] (https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/get-started#request-review) states that you will get a mail after you upload app.

this makes the confusion.

Comment: You should still use the form.  You might be using a different email address than the one registered in the console.

Comment: no i am using the same email address that uploaded the app.

yeah i am using the support form and waiting for their reply.